# Regular Expression for Alphabetic Letter with accent

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I need a validation a texbox in c# and asp.net using Regular Expression.

I need allow:

- alphabetic letters UPPERCASE and lowercase or any ComBINAtion
- accented letters like: èèéàù ...
- numbers
- only one white space " "

I need dot NOT allow:

- any special characters like: |!"£$%&/()<> ...

Any ideas? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If validation occurs *at server side*, you can use the pattern:

```
^\w*(\s\w*)?$
```

`\w` in .Net is Unicode aware - it should include all letters.

Note that `\w` also include the underscore and other word-connectors. You can use `[\p{L}\p{Nd}]` instead of `\w` to disallow them.

See also: [Character Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

This might be a start

```
^([\w\d]+[ ]?)+$
```

\d matches the digits

\w matches "word characters". The.NET RegEx considers unicode characters as word characters. See: http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx

I'm not sure what you mean by "one white space". This expressions allows one space, but not double-spaces, between words.

Comment: This pattern is an excellent example of [Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) - try matching `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!`, and watch your computer fry `:)`. A pattern similar to my own, `^\w*(\s\w*)*$`, would perform much better - it only allows one way to match the input (note that the space isn't optional in this case). Also, note that `\w` already includes `\d`.

Comment: Oh, sorry. That should be something like `^\w*(\s\w+)*\s?$`, which also seems weird, it can probably be done better.